# Unity3d build error duplicate class com.google.unity.ads

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

I can't build my app please help me. I tried everything i saw in the internet:

- delete unity ads package
- delete library
- change sdk build tools version.

Nothing works.

I'm using jdk 1.8.161 (i tried those; 191, 181 but still does not work)

I don't have unity ads in my project.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.

C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.unity.BuildConfig found in modules classes.jar (:googlemobileads-unity:) and unity-plugin-library.jar (unity-plugin-library.jar)
  Duplicate class com.google.unity.ads.AdNetworkExtras found in modules classes.jar (:googlemobileads-unity:) and unity-plugin-library.jar (unity-plugin-library.jar)
  Duplicate class com.google.unity.ads.Banner found in modules classes.jar (:googlemobileads-unity:) and unity-plugin-library.jar (unity-plugin-library.jar)


  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 1m 40s
]
stdout[
> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseManifest
> Task :checkReleaseManifest
> Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :prepareLintJar
> Task :generateReleaseSources
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:prepareLintJar
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseSources
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :mainApkListPersistenceRelease
> Task :generateReleaseResValues
> Task :generateReleaseResources
> Task :mergeReleaseResources
> Task :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :processReleaseManifest
> Task :processReleaseResources
> Task :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :validateSigningRelease
> Task :signingConfigWriterRelease
> Task :checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: I guess following the [link in the error message](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolution_errors) was not an option?

Comment: You have and exception named "checkReleaseDuplicateClasses". So either you have duplicated references or a class declared twice in your code.

Comment: @bradbury9 my project was working before the update. problem started after the using 2019.4.10f (i tried 2018.2.7f and 3.10f.)

Comment: i tried unity 2018.4.12f1. problem still does.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: @thiagolr i delete all ads. packages & assets. you have to delete all ad units. then import again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it could work but I closed Unity, deleted my project **[Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN4Zk.png)** folder and oppened Unity, after that all these errors were solved.

**project Library folder**

[image]

I hope it help

If it does not work you have more info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes)